# Create Snapshot of Wordpress/Mariadb Docker Setup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, mariadb

I have set up Wordpress and MariaDB on a Digital Ocean droplet. Both docker containers use data volumes (`-v /root/mysite/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` and `-v /root/mysite/wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content \`) to persist data on the physical host.

Before I go experimenting on the site that may destroy my setup, how can I take a snapshot of the server setup or docker volumes so I can revert to them is something went wrong?

Can I simply make copies of `/root/mysite/mysql` and `/root/mysite/wordpress` and copy them back to their original locations to revert back to the working state?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I simply make copies of /root/mysite/mysql and
>   /root/mysite/wordpress and copy them back to their original locations
>   to revert back to the working state?

Sure, should work fine. Just make sure to stop MariaDB before making the copy to ensure that all state is saved to the filesystem properly and that the database files are in a consistent state.